# Outlook macro for moving message to HDD works but opening the message gives error

Tags: vba, outlook

I have an Outlook macro to move incoming message to HDD via Outlook rules and it works fine.

But problem is when I open the message on HDD copied via macro, I get this error message

> *"We can't open xxxxx. It's possible the file is already open, or you don't have permission to open it. To check your permissions, right-click the file folder, then click Properties."*

I checked my permissions and found no problem. I also closed Outlook and try to open the saved message but nothing changed, I still get same error message.

How can we solve this error ?

```
Public Sub AutoSave(oMail As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim dtDate As Date
    Dim sName As String
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim sExt As String

    sPath = "C:\Users\xxxuser\Desktop\"
    sExt = ".msg"
    sName = oMail.Subject
    ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "_"
    dtDate = oMail.ReceivedTime
    sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
    vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, "-hhnnss", _
    vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" & sName & sExt

    oMail.SaveAs sPath & sName, olSaveAsMsg

End Sub

Public Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, _
    sChr As String _
    )
    sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "FW:", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "RE:", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `olSaveAsMsg` is wrong and because you didn't use `Option Explicit` you didn't see that. So I recommend to write `Option Explicit` at the top of your module. Then you will see that `olSaveAsMsg` is considered as variable and it is not declared.
It should now throw an error *"Variable is not defined"*.

Because the empty variable probably casts to `0` which means `olTXT` according to [OlSaveAsType Enumeration](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869250(v=office.14).aspx), it is very likely that your message is saved in text format, and therefore Outlook can not open it.

So save it in the Outlook message format it should be

- `olMSG` for *"Outlook message format"* or
- `olMSGUnicode` for *"Outlook Unicode message format"*.

Comment: The macro saves messages as outlook message format successfully not text format as you claim. I see that it's extension is msg, not txt

Comment: @Ergin The extension has nothing to do with the format contained inside the file. So just because you name the extension `.msg` dosn't automatically make the format a Outlook message. Inside the file it can still be a text file. You can rename any extension but that never changes the format inside the file! What we can definitley say is that `olSaveAsMsg` does not exist as you can read in the documentation I linked. So use `Option Explicit` and you will see it.

Comment: @Ergin PEH is correct, it should be `oMail.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMsg`

Comment: Adding Option Explicit and correcting last code as oMail.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMsg fixed my problem. Many thanks all of you for your kind assist.